# Trouble migrating from v1 to v2 of AzureRM using for network interface security group, it fails to apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm migrating my config from azurerm 1.44 to 2.3.0 and need to use the new config item azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association

When I do my plan all seems good:

Terraform will perform the following actions:

```
  # module.web-msg.azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association.main[0] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "main" {
      + id                        = (known after apply)
      + network_interface_id      = "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/vm-0/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/vm-0-nic"
      + network_security_group_id = "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/vm-0/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/MsgHubNetworkSecurityGroup"
    }

  # module.web-msg.azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association.main[1] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "main" {
      + id                        = (known after apply)
      + network_interface_id      = "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/vm-1/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/vm-1-nic"
      + network_security_group_id = "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/vm-1/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/MsgHubNetworkSecurityGroup"
    }
```

But when I come to apply I get this which doesn't make sense as the resource "vm-0" is being managed by terraform.

```
terraform apply .\the.plan
module.web-msg.azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association.main[0]: Creating...
module.web-msg.azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association.main[1]: Creating...

Error: A resource with the ID "vm-0" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" for more information.

  on ..\..\..\infra\terraform\global\msghub\main.tf line 52, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "main":
  52: resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "main" {



Error: A resource with the ID "vm-1" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" for more information.

  on ..\..\..\infra\terraform\global\msghub\main.tf line 52, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "main":
  52: resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "main" {
```

Comment: You need to share your terraform files so that communities can give you the right help.

Comment: as i understand vm-0 and vm-1 are already declared in your tf config, right? Can you share their declarations, please?

Comment: Do you still work on this issue? I didn't see any updates for half a month.

Comment: I'm still working through it in the backgroud, but I think an import of azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association between the plan and apply is needed

Comment: You need to provide the Terraform code so that I can find the mistake in it. I can do nothing if no Terraform code.